# Don't know if bytearray I am receiving is understandable by BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this app in which I have to receive an image in the form of a byte array. That image has been sent to the server, previously, in this way:

```
 image = image.createScaledBitmap((Bitmap) extras.get("data"), 380, 400, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

The image is sent OK to the server. Another part of the application calls the server to get a JSON in which the image is enclosed. I store it in an String, and then I use `string.getBytes()` to get the byte array, something like that:

```
byte[] array=stringimage.getbytes();
```

The array is something like: 119,80,78,71,13,10...

I think now "ok, I use now BitmapFactory,decodeByteArray and get my Bitmap" but it returns null. I start Googling and looking here in Stack Overflow and I see various approaches to the problem. One of that:

```
image = Bitmap.createBitmap(380, 400, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
int row = 0, col = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
    image.setPixel(col++, row, array[i + 2] & array[i + 1] & array[i]);
    
    if (col == 380) {
        col = 0;
        row++;
        
    }
}
```

That is something like decode the image and set the pixels by hand.

It doesn't work.

Another one:

```
byte[] array=Base64.decode(fotostring.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

It doesn't work

My question is: How must I ask my mate, who is in charge of the server side, to send me the array? in which format? he does not touch the image I send him previously in any way. Does he need to do?

Or, how I must manage the byte array? Do I need no "translate" to another format, one that decodeByteArray can understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of the encoding / decoding. The byte array that you received from the image is binary and cannot be interpreted as text. For transferring it over a text-based protocol (I assume you would have used HTTP), you will have to encode it into a textual format.  The symmetrical operation need to be performed when you receive it from the server.

When you send it to the server, encode in a format (say Base64) and use the same format to decode the received string.